# When giving % width, table's body reduces total space to Head's col 1 space

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a table with px widths. The only thing I am changing are those px to %. When table receives new values, table's header and footer accept them correctly and take the correct position. But table's body reacts taking its total width as the width of only the first column. This means the 4 columns collapse into the first one, and leving the next 3 columns blank.

Here I explain with images.

**Before: width on px.** Each column on the body matches with each column on head:

[image: Table with PX widths]

Code involved:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    color:#666;
    font-size:12px;
    background:#eaebec;
    margin:10px;
    border:#ccc 1px solid;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
    table-layout: fixed;}
.discontinueColumn{
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 90px;}
.editColumn{
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 90px;}
.headerScroll{
    width: 16px;}
tbody{
    display: block;
    height: 360px;
    width: 900px;
        overflow-y: auto; }
.contentColumn_turn_conf1{
    width:549px;}
.contentColumn_turn_conf2{
    width:149px;}
```

---

**After: width on %.** All body's columns reduce it's total space to head's first column width:

[image: table with % widths]

Code involved:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    color:#666;
    font-size:12px;
    background:#eaebec;
    margin:10px;
    border:#ccc 1px solid;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
    table-layout: fixed;}
.discontinueColumn{
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 10%;}
.editColumn{
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 10%;}
.headerScroll{
    width: 4%;  }
tbody{
    display: block;
    height: 360px;
    width: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto; }
.contentColumn_turn_conf1{
    width:60%;}
.contentColumn_turn_conf2{
    width:20%;}
```

As you can see, on the last one body's 100% width is reduced to head's first column width. On code you can appreciate only width values have changed. Why is this happening? Any additional code please let me know.

This is what it runs when pasting code: [jsfiddle.net/6XWRK](http://jsfiddle.net/6XWRK/)

Comment: have you fixed the issue ?

Comment: At least I had a meeting with my teacher. He did not ven explain me how to solve this with tables. We built a table made of Div's exactly the same as it was with <table>, working perfectly with lopped data coming from PHP, and quite more easy to build and modify than working with tables. He hates tables and in deed I should have choosen Div opction from the begining... Anyway thank you for your attention @bboymaanu

Comment: I was too busy in last couple of days and I am happy to hear that found alternative. Teachers seems to be always busy at the same time we developers are not like that on HUNTING bugs. Let me see is there any thing I can do for the issue

Comment: Not at all, it is entirely solved and now it is working almost perfecty, I am now adjusting small details but it is quite better working with divs as often as possible, rather than tables. Much more possibilities, easyest, more flexible. Very grateful for your help and attention.

Answer (score 1):

you gave `display: block;` to a `<tbody>` which is not good since it is `display: table-row-group` by default.

This could be what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/4Eak6/
Let the table header define the column width.

```
table {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    border-spacing: 0;
    color:#666;
    font-size:12px;
    background:#eaebec;
    margin:10px;
    border:#ccc 1px solid;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
    table-layout: auto;
}
.discontinueColumn {
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 10%;
}
.editColumn {
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 10%;
}
.headerScroll {
    width: 4%;
}
tbody {
    height: 360px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.contentColumn_turn_conf1 {
    width:60%;
}
.contentColumn_turn_conf2 {
    width:20%;
}
```

**Edit:**

From the source I guess you want floating table headers. So here is demo for that: http://jsfiddle.net/4Eak6/1/ using the jQuery Framework and floatThead Plugin. Maybe it's a help for you.

Comment: Thank you Nico. When I take block out, it does give a proper width to each column, but take a look at the result: http://prntscr.com/2yf8up 
And I am not able to say to every tr that is must be 40 px height (neither with max-height or height).

Comment: you can, if you want that the content has no line-breaks. Add `table-layout: fixed; white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden;` Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Eak6/2/

Comment: Hi Nico. I am afraid no result with this neither. I am going to have a look at the jQuery plugin you mention, in case this solves my problem I'll inform you and tick your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: what do you mean with no result? my Demo is cutting of a long `<td>` content to stay at a max height. What wrong? The JS-solution will only make your headers fixed, which i guess you wanted by the overflow property in the table body.

Comment: I have added followig your instructions the white-space:nowrap and the overflow:hidden, and visually it has only increased footer's height. All lines keep on occuping the whole body: http://prntscr.com/2yfe7e

Comment: Look this: http://jsfiddle.net/4Eak6/3/ the first column has a lot of content but it is getting cut off. Analyse the CSS in the Jsfiddle and compare it with yours- Like you can see it have to work.

Comment: Yes, in deed they are working exactly the same: width is Ok, but height always takes 100% of body's heigth. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/4Eak6/4/ it s your example but with only 3 or 4 rows. each row must have a fixed 40 px height, and the rest of the table body remain empty, in order to always have a 360px body height with 40px height rows.

Comment: Sorry jsfiddle link was wrong. If you leave just 3 rows on your table you'll see they dont take  fixed height.

Comment: Nope. Without height, it stills fixes total rows heights to its height. Tabe must have a fixed height as footer must always be on the same position, I've tried also setting total height to tbale instead to body, ad no result: http://prntscr.com/2yfk5b